# 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x005EF9E4

Tags: c++

I am having issues with Handles. I have Bytebeat (music in bytes) playing inside of a DWORD WINAPI function. When I try to terminate and close the thread, it straight up gives me the error in the title. This is my code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Winmm.lib")

DWORD WINAPI bytebeat1(LPVOID) {
    while (1) {
        HWAVEOUT hwo = 0;
        WAVEFORMATEX wfx = { WAVE_FORMAT_PCM, 1, 11000, 11000, 1, 8, 0 };
        waveOutOpen(&hwo, WAVE_MAPPER, &wfx, 0, 0, CALLBACK_NULL);

        char buffer[11000 * 6];

        for (DWORD t = 0; t < sizeof(buffer); t++)
            buffer[t] = static_cast<char>(t & t + t / 256) - t * (t >> 15) & 64;

        WAVEHDR hdr = { buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        waveOutPrepareHeader(hwo, &hdr, sizeof(WAVEHDR));
        waveOutWrite(hwo, &hdr, sizeof(WAVEHDR));
        waveOutUnprepareHeader(hwo, &hdr, sizeof(WAVEHDR));
        waveOutClose(hwo);
        Sleep(6000);
    }
}

DWORD WINAPI bytebeat2(LPVOID) {
    while (1) {
        HWAVEOUT hwo = 0;
        WAVEFORMATEX wfx = { WAVE_FORMAT_PCM, 1, 8000, 8000, 1, 8, 0 };
        waveOutOpen(&hwo, WAVE_MAPPER, &wfx, 0, 0, CALLBACK_NULL);

        char buffer[8000 * 6];

        for (DWORD t = 0; t < sizeof(buffer); t++)
            buffer[t] = static_cast<char>(t, t / 5) >> t / 25 & t / 55 ^ t & 255 ^ (t / 150) ^ 2508025 * 24240835810 & (t / 100) * t / 6000 ^ 5000 * t / 2500 ^ 25 * t / 24;

        WAVEHDR hdr = { buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        waveOutPrepareHeader(hwo, &hdr, sizeof(WAVEHDR));
        waveOutWrite(hwo, &hdr, sizeof(WAVEHDR));
        waveOutUnprepareHeader(hwo, &hdr, sizeof(WAVEHDR));
        waveOutClose(hwo);
        Sleep(6000);
    }
}

int main() {
    HANDLE beat1 = CreateThread(0, 0, bytebeat1, 0, 0, 0);
    Sleep(6000);
    TerminateThread(beat1, 0); CloseHandle(beat1);
    Sleep(1000);
    HANDLE beat2 = CreateThread(0, 0, bytebeat2, 0, 0, 0);
    Sleep(6000);
    TerminateThread(beat2, 0); CloseHandle(beat2);
}
```

I do not know why this is happening. The only fix is compiling it with G++ but I want it so I could just build it. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You should read the [remarks section for TerminateThread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-terminatethread#remarks).  TerminateThread is a dangerous function that should only be used in the most extreme cases.  Only call it when you know exactly what point the thread is at.  e.g. deadlocked on some specific wait handle or something - certainly not when it is actually running. It could exit in the middle of a malloc/free operation for example, corrupting the process's heap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call TerminateThread, you are basically force-crashing your threads. They still have their own stack allocated and handles to Windows resources. They aren't cleaned up properly, causing your crash.

Here's a simple example of how to close your threads without any error. In a real-world scenario this is an unprofessional solution, but it shows the bare minimum that you need to do.

```
#include <windows.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Winmm.lib")

volatile bool quit1 = false;
volatile bool quit2 = false;

DWORD WINAPI bytebeat1(LPVOID) {
    while (!quit1) {
        HWAVEOUT hwo = 0;
        WAVEFORMATEX wfx = { WAVE_FORMAT_PCM, 1, 11000, 11000, 1, 8, 0 };
        waveOutOpen(&hwo, WAVE_MAPPER, &wfx, 0, 0, CALLBACK_NULL);

        char buffer[11000 * 6];

        for (DWORD t = 0; t < sizeof(buffer); t++)
            buffer[t] = static_cast<char>(t & t + t / 256) - t * (t >> 15) & 64;

        WAVEHDR hdr = { buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        waveOutPrepareHeader(hwo, &hdr, sizeof(WAVEHDR));
        waveOutWrite(hwo, &hdr, sizeof(WAVEHDR));
        waveOutUnprepareHeader(hwo, &hdr, sizeof(WAVEHDR));
        waveOutClose(hwo);
        Sleep(6000);
    }

    return 0;
}

DWORD WINAPI bytebeat2(LPVOID) {
    while (!quit2) {
        HWAVEOUT hwo = 0;
        WAVEFORMATEX wfx = { WAVE_FORMAT_PCM, 1, 8000, 8000, 1, 8, 0 };
        waveOutOpen(&hwo, WAVE_MAPPER, &wfx, 0, 0, CALLBACK_NULL);

        char buffer[8000 * 6];

        for (DWORD t = 0; t < sizeof(buffer); t++)
            buffer[t] = static_cast<char>(t, t / 5) >> t / 25 & t / 55 ^ t & 255 ^ (t / 150) ^ 2508025 * 24240835810 & (t / 100) * t / 6000 ^ 5000 * t / 2500 ^ 25 * t / 24;

        WAVEHDR hdr = { buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        waveOutPrepareHeader(hwo, &hdr, sizeof(WAVEHDR));
        waveOutWrite(hwo, &hdr, sizeof(WAVEHDR));
        waveOutUnprepareHeader(hwo, &hdr, sizeof(WAVEHDR));
        waveOutClose(hwo);
        Sleep(6000);
    }

    return 0;
}

int main() {
    HANDLE beat1 = CreateThread(0, 0, bytebeat1, 0, 0, 0);
    Sleep(6000);
    quit1 = true;
    WaitForSingleObject(beat1, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(beat1);
    Sleep(1000);
    HANDLE beat2 = CreateThread(0, 0, bytebeat2, 0, 0, 0);
    Sleep(6000);
    quit2 = true;
    WaitForSingleObject(beat2, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(beat2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! For some reason, when I do GDI effects my program doesn't crash.

Answer (score 2):

As the documentation makes clear, you can't use `TerminateThread` this way. Instead, replace the calls to `Sleep` with an interruptible sleep function that will terminate the thread cleanly and safely if requested to do so.

Comment: To be even more blunt:  If you are using the `TerminateThread` function you are doing something wrong.  Do not EVER use this function.   In 30+ years of Windows software development I have never needed it.  Threads should do their work and then call the appropriate Wait function (there are many variations of it) to wait on the appropriate set of handles/conditions until told to do more work or to exit normally.  If you are using the Win32 API, this is what you do.